# Wrong selection from database using Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a method that selects two fields from database where text in first field match some value

```
public static List<List<string>> SelectForSearch(string letter)
{
    var data = (from p in model.City
                where p.Name.StartsWith(letter)
                select new List<string> { p.Name, p.CountryName }).ToList();
    return data;
}
```

But it returns me a list like this:

> [0][0]Australia
> [0][1]Ballina
>
> [1][0]Berry
> [1][1]Australia
>
> [2][0]Australia
> [2][1]Bendigo
> ...

Country and City possition don't have a static index like this:

> [0][0]Ballina
> [0][1]Australia
>
> [1][0]Berry
> [1][1]Australia
>
> [2][0]Bendigo
> [2][1]Australia
> ...

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that in your select statement, instead of creating a type with Name and CountryName you are creating a List of strings. The List initialiser allows you to pass in the values when the list is constructed by placing them in `{ }` and you are using this ability by accident, as you saw it creates a list of strings where the name is the first element and the country name is the second element. What you want to be doing is more like:

```
var data = (from p in model.City
            where p.Name.StartsWith(letter)
            select new { City = p.Name, CountryName = p.CountryName }).ToList();
return data;
```

This is using anonymous types which is not good as you want to declare a type for the return value. So you should really create a class for storage, for example:

```
public class CityCountryPair 
{
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

then your method becomes

```
public static List<CityCountryPair> SelectForSearch(string letter)
{
    var data = (from p in model.City
                where p.Name.StartsWith(letter)
                select new CityCountryPair() { City = p.Name, 
                                               CountryName = p.CountryName 
                                              }).ToList();
    return data;
}
```